# GraphQL Subscription Authentication Using AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, graphql, express-graphql

Am trying to use subscription on my client app to send **JWT Token and refreshToken** to the server using WebSocketLink **connectionParams**. But the problem is that my token and refreshToken are saved inside AsynStorage that require me to use async await to get the value out. 
When i tried to use await, it send undefined to the server.

Here is the code below:

```
// Create a WebSocket link:
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: wsUri,
    options: {
        reconnect: true,
        connectionParams: async () => {
            return {
                token: await AsyncStorage.getItem('token'),
                refreshToken: await AsyncStorage.getItem('refreshToken')
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If i set a plan key, it will work. But i need to get the tokens form Async storage using await. How can i go about it?

Comment: In the latest version `0.9.8` of `subscriptions-transport-ws`, it still doesn't support `connectionParams` return a promise. But it had a pull request relate to this issue, and you can refer it https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/pull/348

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy. Thanks for the link. but it has not being merged yet. Can i edit the code in my node_module and check it out if it can make it work?

Comment: You can fork and edit it yourself or just change some code of `SubscriptionClient.prototype.connect` in `client` file in `node_modules`

Comment: I just tried changing the file now but what's in the pull request is normal Js code but what i found is typescript. And the PR make reference to src/client.ts but what i found in the folder is dist/client.js

Comment: Yeah, you can change in `dist/client.js`, just found `SubscriptionClient.prototype.connect` and edit it like the way that pull request does. But you should fork that project, edit and build for long term using.

Comment: I've got it working. Thanks for the help!